# Xml from url to c#

Tags: c#, xml

I can't parse xml from a url to c#. I have the following code and it gives an error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (1, 17):

I have to download the xml parse it and save the data to the storage, but for many hours I was able to write only such code and I can't understand what to work on here.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;


public class categories
{
    public string parentId;
    public int categoryId;

    [XmlElement("categories")]
    public List<categories> categoriess;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("(categories) name: {0}, age: {1}\n", parentId, categoryId) +
            string.Join("", categoriess.Select(x => x.ToString()));
    }
}

public class Test
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    public static void Main()
    {
        String URLString = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sSR9kWifwjIP5qFWcyxGCxN0-MoEd_oo/view";
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);
        var result = (categories)new XmlSerializer(typeof(categories)).Deserialize(reader);

            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        }
}
```

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<!DOCTYPE yml_catalog SYSTEM "shops.dtd">
<yml_catalog date="2021-07-22 12:07">
<shop>
    <name>Radio-Liga</name>
    <company>Magazine</company>
    <url>http://www.radio-liga.ru/</url>
    
    <currencies>
        <currency id="RUR"/>
    </currencies>
    
    <categories>
        <category id="544">CI-BI AutoStations</category>
        <category id="499" parentId="544">ALAN</category>
        <category id="513" parentId="544">MEGAJET</category>
        <category id="514" parentId="544">YOSAN</category>
        <category id="571" parentId="544">PRESIDENT</category>
        <category id="559" parentId="544">ALBRECHT</category>
        <category id="565" parentId="544">OPTIM</category>
        <category id="727" parentId="544">VECTOR</category>
        <category id="498" parentId="545">MIDLAND</category>
        <category id="528" parentId="545">ROGER</category>
        <category id="603" parentId="545">BAOFENG</category>>
        <category id="604" parentId="545">LIRA</category>
        <category id="626" parentId="545">TYT</category>
        <category id="680" parentId="545">TURBOSKY</category>
        <category id="681" parentId="545">COMRADE </category>
```

Comment: That xml you posted is invalid.

Comment: this is part of the xml the rest is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sSR9kWifwjIP5qFWcyxGCxN0-MoEd_oo/view

Answer (score -1):

You haven't posted the whole XML here, so it's hard to tell. Also, the error message looks incomplete.

It could be a problem with the encoding="windows-1251". Some parsers won't recognise this encoding.

It could be a problem with the DTD (the reference to shops.dtd).

When you can't solve an XML parsing error the easiest solution is sometimes to paste the document into a different XML editor - some of them typically have better diagnostics than others.